# C++ exceptions not getting caught with GNU gcc libstdc++ 4.3.6 on AIX 7.1

Tags: c++, exception, gcc, aix, libstdc++

I'm trying to get a port of our product to AIX that someone did 9 years ago working again, so I'm using gcc 4.3.6 on AIX 7.1 - the code builds without errors, and runs until we first throw an exception, but then the catch block that should catch it (and does on Linux) never gets called, and the execution terminates due to the uncaught exception. I've added test code where the throw and the catch are in the same function, so that it's not trying to cross any module boundaries or do any stack unwinding, and even that doesn't work:

```
try {
    throw std::runtime_error("Just testing throw-catch");
} catch (std::runtime_error& e) {
    // We don't get here
```

So it seems like something is very sick in our libstdc++ exception handling. The gcc & libstdc++ 4.3.6 we're using are from RPMs downloaded from the www.perzl.org/aix repository, so they should be built correctly, and looking at the autoconf log from setting up our makefiles for AIX they seem to have been located correctly. So I'm guessing it must be something in our environment or the linking process for my executable. We're using the preinstalled  (on a VM provided by IBM) AIX native linker ld, rather than the gnu linker, which I gather is the correct thing to do on AIX. I've confirmed that the libstdc++.a library archive that we're using contains a .so library, so I believe we're linking libstdc++ dynamically. If it's relevant, here's some gory details of build flags etc:

```
/usr/local/tools/powerpc_AIX71/gcc-4.3.6/bin/g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../.. -I/usr/nimbus/nimbus/agent/util/tests  -I/usr/local/tools/powerpc_AIX71/cppunit/include -I/usr/nimbus/nimbus/agent  -I/usr/local/tools/powerpc_AIX71/boost-1.33.1/include -DECVERSION='"7.2.0.0"' -I/usr/local/tools/powerpc_AIX71/openssl-0.9.8y/include -I/usr/nimbus/nimbus/agent  -I/usr/local/tools/powerpc_AIX71/boost-1.33.1/include -DECVERSION='"7.2.0.0"'  -DUSE_PROFILING -DUSE_LOGGING -DHAVE_UNIX -DHAVE_AIX  -g -O2 -c -o testrunner-TestSystem-unix.o `test -f 'unix/TestSystem-unix.cpp' || echo '/usr/nimbus/nimbus/agent/util/tests/'`unix/TestSystem-unix.cpp
rm -f buildinfo.cpp; echo '#include <util/buildinfo.h>' >buildinfo.cpp; echo >>buildinfo.cpp; echo 'const char *BuildInfo = "u0016760__0_OPT_2017.02.08_10:38:05";' >>buildinfo.cpp; /usr/local/tools/powerpc_AIX71/gcc-4.3.6/bin/g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../.. -I/usr/nimbus/nimbus/agent/util/tests  -I/usr/nimbus/nimbus/agent  -I/usr/local/tools/powerpc_AIX71/boost-1.33.1/include -DECVERSION='"7.2.0.0"'  -DUSE_PROFILING -DUSE_LOGGING -DHAVE_UNIX -DHAVE_AIX  -g -O2 -c buildinfo.cpp; /opt/freeware/bin/bash ../../libtool --tag=CXX   --mode=link /usr/local/tools/powerpc_AIX71/gcc-4.3.6/bin/g++ -DUSE_PROFILING -DUSE_LOGGING -DHAVE_UNIX -DHAVE_AIX  -g -O2 -static-libgcc -L../..   -o testrunner buildinfo.o testrunner-TestAtomicValue.o testrunner-TestCondition.o testrunner-TestCounter.o testrunner-TestECVersion.o testrunner-TestExec.o testrunner-TestExecTimeProfiler.o testrunner-TestExpirableStack.o testrunner-TestFileAttributes.o testrunner-TestGetOpt.o testrunner-TestHTTPStream.o testrunner-TestLock.o testrunner-TestLogger.o testrunner-TestMutex.o testrunner-TestNamedTimer.o testrunner-TestRBList.o testrunner-TestRange.o testrunner-TestRefCount.o testrunner-TestServerSocket.o testrunner-TestSlidingWindow.o testrunner-TestSSLSocket.o testrunner-TestSSLSocketFactory.o testrunner-TestSingleton.o testrunner-TestStringKey.o testrunner-TestStringUtilities.o testrunner-TestSubString.o testrunner-TestSystem.o testrunner-TestTCPRawStream.o testrunner-TestTCPSocket.o testrunner-TestTCPStream.o testrunner-TestThreadPool.o testrunner-TestTSDVar.o testrunner-TestTask.o testrunner-TestThread.o testrunner-TestTicks.o testrunner-TestTime.o testrunner-TestTimer.o testrunner-TestWinEnv.o testrunner-Testfilefun.o testrunner-TinyHTTP.o testrunner-Testpathfun.o testrunner-utiltestutil.o  testrunner-TestDouble.o testrunner-TestLockedFile-unix.o testrunner-TestSystem-unix.o ../../testmain/libtestmain.a -L/usr/local/tools/powerpc_AIX71/cppunit/lib -lcppunit ../../util/libutil.a -lpthread -L/usr/local/tools/powerpc_AIX71/openssl-0.9.8y/lib -lssl -lcrypto
libtool: link: warning: library `/usr/local/tools/powerpc_AIX71/cppunit/lib/libcppunit.la' was moved.
libtool: link: warning: library `/usr/local/tools/powerpc_AIX71/cppunit/lib/libcppunit.la' was moved.
/usr/local/tools/powerpc_AIX71/gcc-4.3.6/bin/g++ -DUSE_PROFILING -DUSE_LOGGING -DHAVE_UNIX -DHAVE_AIX -g -O2 -static-libgcc -o testrunner buildinfo.o testrunner-TestAtomicValue.o testrunner-TestCondition.o testrunner-TestCounter.o testrunner-TestECVersion.o testrunner-TestExec.o testrunner-TestExecTimeProfiler.o testrunner-TestExpirableStack.o testrunner-TestFileAttributes.o testrunner-TestGetOpt.o testrunner-TestHTTPStream.o testrunner-TestLock.o testrunner-TestLogger.o testrunner-TestMutex.o testrunner-TestNamedTimer.o testrunner-TestRBList.o testrunner-TestRange.o testrunner-TestRefCount.o testrunner-TestServerSocket.o testrunner-TestSlidingWindow.o testrunner-TestSSLSocket.o testrunner-TestSSLSocketFactory.o testrunner-TestSingleton.o testrunner-TestStringKey.o testrunner-TestStringUtilities.o testrunner-TestSubString.o testrunner-TestSystem.o testrunner-TestTCPRawStream.o testrunner-TestTCPSocket.o testrunner-TestTCPStream.o testrunner-TestThreadPool.o testrunner-TestTSDVar.o testrunner-TestTask.o testrunner-TestThread.o testrunner-TestTicks.o testrunner-TestTime.o testrunner-TestTimer.o testrunner-TestWinEnv.o testrunner-Testfilefun.o testrunner-TinyHTTP.o testrunner-Testpathfun.o testrunner-utiltestutil.o testrunner-TestDouble.o testrunner-TestLockedFile-unix.o testrunner-TestSystem-unix.o  -L/usr/nimbus/out/powerpc_AIX71/nimbus/agent ../../testmain/libtestmain.a -L/usr/local/tools/powerpc_AIX71/cppunit/lib /usr/local/tools/powerpc_AIX71/cppunit/lib/libcppunit.a ../../util/libutil.a -lpthread -L/usr/local/tools/powerpc_AIX71/openssl-0.9.8y/lib -lssl -lcrypto
ld: 0711-224 WARNING: Duplicate symbol: .bcopy
ld: 0711-224 WARNING: Duplicate symbol: .virtual thunk to CppUnit::OStringStream::~OStringStream()
ld: 0711-224 WARNING: Duplicate symbol: .virtual thunk to CppUnit::OStringStream::~OStringStream()
ld: 0711-224 WARNING: Duplicate symbol: virtual thunk to CppUnit::OStringStream::~OStringStream()
ld: 0711-224 WARNING: Duplicate symbol: virtual thunk to CppUnit::OStringStream::~OStringStream()
ld: 0711-345 Use the -bloadmap or -bnoquiet option to obtain more information.
```

The various warnings look unrelated to me. Does anyone have any suggestions of what to check next?

Comment: [***Huh!!*** What please?](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/46d8e78511b98fed). Provide a [MCVE] that reproduces your problem please.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ That's not on AIX though. Roger writes that it runs OK on Linux.

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=61637 related?

Comment: I experience the same problem but with GCC 5.1.0 while on GCC 4.8.5 I do not have any problem. Have you compiled GCC on your own?

Comment: Here is also a related link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42121236/c-exceptions-not-getting-caught-with-gnu-gcc-libstdc-4-3-6-on-aix-7-1#new-answer

Comment: A first step would be to get the build process right, related or not.